# Cron Task stops at same time every day?

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash script which runs, reliably, every 15 minutes until 08:30 each day. No errors are generated by the task itself which leads me to believe there may be something else causing cron tasks to fail at this time each day..

Can anyone suggest how I would begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What are you seeing that makes you believe that cron tasks are failing? And, coincidentally, what time each day do your cron.daily tasks run?

Comment: */15 * * * *  /home/[username]/scripts/run_speedtest.sh >> /home/[username]/logs/speedtest.log

The log records the script running up until that time, then no more results are recorded until I (a) notice and (b) reload cron which kicks off the 15 minute intervals again.. I have nothing to go on apart from the time that the cron appears to cease it's 15 minute intervals so I'm unsure what else I can provide which may help figure it out - it could well be my dodgy bash script, aside from the consistency of time that it fails daily (could still be my dodgy script..)

Comment: If you disable the line in your crontab that triggers your script, do other cron jobs continue to run after 0830?

Comment: Have not tried that - will set something up and run it to see - good idea, Thanks!